# CSS-only push menu navigation

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation, toggle

I'm using a CSS only push nav on my one page website. So when you click on the menu icon, the nav pops out from the side of the page, and when you click it again, it hides. Since it's a one page site, when you click on a nav link it will jump to another section of the page. The menu works great, however I can't seem to get it to hide when I click on a nav link! When it jumps to another section, the menu just stays where it is, which I don't want.

If someone knows how I could make the menu hide when the site jumps to another section, please let me know!

Here's the html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu" class="menu-checkbox">
<div class="menu">  
<label class="menu-toggle" for="menu"><span>Toggle</span></label>
<ul class="mainnav">
  <li><a class="text-right" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
  <li><a class="text-right" href="#process">PROCESS</a></li>
  <li><a class="text-right" href="#work">WORK</a></li>
  <li><a class="text-right" href="#contact">CONTACT</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

And here's the CSS:

```
label{
cursor: pointer;
&:focus;
outline: none;
}

.menu{
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
background-color: rgba(111, 206, 204, 0.7);
width: 240px;
height: 100%;
z-index: 10;
}

label.menu-toggle{
position: absolute;    
right: -60px;
width: 75px;
height: 90px;
line-height: 0px;  
display: block;
margin-top: 30px; 
margin-right: -50px;
padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
text-indent: -9999px;
background: 50% 50% / 45px 32px no-repeat;
background-image:url(../images/menu.png);
}


a, label{
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.menu-checkbox{
display: none;
}

.menu .menu label.menu-toggle{
background: none;
}

.menu-checkbox:checked + .menu{
transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
-webkit-transition: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
```

I know I need to toggle the hidden checkbox to close the menu, I just don't really know how.

Comment: can you share a link i can't see the menu button. btw do you know jquery or javascript?

Comment: i dunno if this will help but its an example of show hide using css http://jsfiddle.net/z5p26kcc/1/

Comment: http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/

here's the link! see how when you use the menu it doesn't automatically hide? it just stays there while the page scrolls down

Comment: i couldnt  figure it out god knows i tried! i thiink you should look at using this model http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNXMpR anyway here is a fiddle of it if you post the question again http://jsfiddle.net/ex7jthnn/28/ or if you just wanna tinker with it

Comment: I'll try it, thank you for trying!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/ex7jthnn/33/

Comment: i just realised my number 28 worked! its in your code! you owe me an accept dear!

Comment: i was just editing so much my computer probably stopped refreshing

Comment: i'd appreciate an upvote too..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Done! with a bit of jquery

```js
$('.menu-toggle').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').css({
    "translate(100%,100%)"
  });
});

$('.close-btn-mail').on('click', function() {
  $('.menu').css({
    "transform": "translate(-100%,-100%)"
  });

});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";

/* CSS Document */

p {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 16px;
}
h2 {
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
  color: #595959;
  font-size: 35px;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}
label {
  cursor: pointer;
  &: focus;
  outline: none;
}
.menu {
  display: block;
}
.hide-list {
  display: none;
}
.menu {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: rgba(111, 206, 204, 0.7);
  width: 240px;
  height: 100%;
  margin-left: 0px;
  transform: translate3d(-240px, 0, 0);
  transition-property: all .2s ease-in;
  -moz-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -webkit-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: all .2s ease-in;
  z-index: 10;
}
.container .expanded {
  width: 220px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container .collapsed {
  width: 220px;
  margin-left: 220px;
  overflow: visible;
}
label.menu-toggle {
  position: absolute;
  right: -60px;
  width: 75px;
  height: 90px;
  line-height: 0px;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
  margin-right: -50px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
  text-indent: -9999px;
  background: 50% 50% / 45px 32px no-repeat;
  background-image: url(http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/menu.png);
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
  transition-property: all;
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition-delay: 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.2s ease-in 0s;
  -webkit-transition-property: all;
  -webkit-transition-duration: 0.2s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  -webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
}
a,
label {
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
/* hide inputs */

.menu-checkbox {
  display: none;
}
/* hide navigation icon for sublabels */

.menu .menu label.menu-toggle {
  background: none;
}
/* fade in checked menu */

.menu-checkbox:checked + .menu {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.menu-checkbox:checked + .menu .menu .container ul.mainnav li a:visited {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}
.logo {
  max-width: 260px;
  margin-top: -15px;
}
#mainHeader {
  background-image: url(http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/desk.jpg);
  background-size: 100% auto;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
#mainHeader ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
}
#mainHeader a {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0.7;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#mainHeader ul li a:hover {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}
#mainHeader ul {
  padding-top: 60px;
}
#info {
  display: table;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#info-content {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
}
h1 {
  color: #fff;
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  text-align: center;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
  font-size: 22px;
  font-weight: normal;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
}
strong {
  display: block;
  font-size: 26px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #mainHeader {
    background-image: url(http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/desk2.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  #mainHeader {
    background-image: url(http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/desk3.jpg);
  }
  .menu-checkbox:checked + .menu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  .menu {
    background-color: rgba(111, 206, 204, 0.8);
  }
  #mainHeader a {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 300;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0.7;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top: -4px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 440px) {
  #mainHeader {
    background-image: url(http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/desk4.jpg);
  }
}
/*About*/

#about {
  padding-top: 70px;
}
.aboutMe {
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #595959;
}
#hey {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.decor {
  margin-top: -8px;
}
.aboutInfo {
  padding-left: 130px;
  padding-right: 130px;
}
#aves {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 17%;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 70px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1240px) {
  .aboutInfo {
    padding-left: 210px;
    padding-right: 210px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .aboutInfo {
    padding-left: 120px;
    padding-right: 120px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 815px) {
  .decor {
    width: 250px;
    margin-top: -8px;
  }
  .aboutMe {
    font-size: 35px;
  }
  #aves {
    width: 25%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 694px) {
  .decor {
    width: 200px;
  }
  .aboutMe {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 680px) {
  .aboutInfo {
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 641px) {
  .decor1 {
    width: 180px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  .decor2 {
    width: 180px;
    padding-left: 20px;
  }
  .aboutMe {
    font-size: 33px;
  }
  #aves {
    width: 30%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 543px) {
  .decor1 {
    width: 120px;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  .decor2 {
    width: 120px;
    margin-left: 10px;
  }
  .aboutMe {
    font-size: 40px;
  }
  .aboutInfo {
    font-size: 20px;
  }
  .aboutInfo {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    margin-top: 15px;
  }
  #aves {
    width: 40%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .decor1 {
    width: 85px;
    margin-right: -5px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  .decor2 {
    width: 85px;
    margin-left: -5px;
    margin-top: -10px;
  }
  .aboutMe {
    font-size: 32px;
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .aboutInfo {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
  }
  #aves {
    width: 50%;
  }
  .menu {}
}
#iLove {
  background-image: url(../images/a_back.jpg);
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-size: 100% auto;
  height: 1289px;
  width: 100%;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.iLovetitle {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
.line {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 15%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.Aback {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  max-width: 100%;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 1588px) {
  .Aback {
    min-width: 2000px;
    height: 1500px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1216px) {
  #iLove {
    height: 1109px;
    background-image: url(../images/a_back2.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1034px) {
  #iLove {
    height: 1009px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) {
  .iLovetitle {
    margin-top: 60px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 954px) {
  #iLove {
    height: 900px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 954px) {
  #iLove {
    background-image: url(../images/a_back3.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 846px) {
  #iLove {
    background-image: url(../images/a_back3.jpg);
    height: 820px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 771px) {
  #iLove {
    background-image: url(../images/a_back4.jpg);
    height: 700px;
  }
  .iLovetitle {
    margin-top: 25px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 679px) {
  .iLovetitle {
    font-size: 30px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 658px) {
  #iLove {
    height: 585px;
    background-image: url(../images/a_back5.jpg);
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 548px) {
  #iLove {
    height: 500px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  #iLove {
    background-image: url(../images/a_back6.jpg);
    height: 485px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 456px) {
  #iLove {
    height: 400px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 377px) {
  #iLove {
    background-image: url(../images/a_back6.jpg);
    height: 360px;
  }
}
/* Process */

#process {
  margin-left: 90px;
  margin-right: 90px;
  height: 700px;
}
.procTitle {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.line2 {
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 15%;
  padding-top: 15px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}
.icon1 {
  margin-left: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
  padding-top: 50px;
  width: 60%;
}
.iconTitle {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  color: #6FCECC;
}
.iconP {
  font-size: 15px;
  padding-right: 12px;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1216px) {
  #process {
    padding-top: 70px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1147px) {
  #process {
    margin-left: 25px;
    margin-right: 25px;
  }
  .procTitle {
    margin-top: -80px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
  #process {
    height: 1030px;
  }
  .icon1 {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    width: 40%;
  }
  .procTitle {
    padding-top: 10px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
  #process {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    height: 1690px;
  }
  .icon1 {
    display: table;
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 30%;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .procTitle {
    font-size: 25px;
    padding-top: 0px;
  }
  .line2 {
    padding-bottom: 40px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .procTitle {
    margin-top: -20px;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .procTitle {
    margin-top: -50px;
  }
}
/*Work*/

#lineDivide {
  border: 1px #EAEAEA solid;
}
.myWork {
  font-family: 'Cookie', cursive;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: #595959;
  display: table;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 70px;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}
/*Gallery*/

.contain {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-orient: horizontal;
  -webkit-box-direction: normal;
  -webkit-flex-direction: row;
  -ms-flex-direction: row;
  flex-direction: row;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
}
.contain .box {
  height: 90%;
  width: 25.333%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100%;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  -webkit-transition: background-size 0.275s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-size 0.275s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-box-flex: 1;
  -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
  -ms-flex-positive: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
}
.contain .box:hover {
  background-size: 115%;
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(1) {
  background-image: url(../images/car_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(2) {
  background-image: url(../images/tshirt_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(3) {
  background-image: url(../images/spa_thumb2.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(4) {
  background-image: url(../images/mcore.jpg);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(5) {
  background-image: url(../images/forrats_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(6) {
  background-image: url(../images/projectx_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(7) {
  background-image: url(../images/gap_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(8) {
  background-image: url(../images/car_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box:nth-of-type(9) {
  background-image: url(../images/tshirt_thumb.png);
}
.contain .box .box-info {
  background: rgba(35, 35, 35, 0.7);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 120%;
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.45s ease-in-out;
  transition: opacity 0.45s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 20% 0 0;
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-family: "Lato", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
}
.contain .box .box-info:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
.imgP {
  height: 240px;
  color: #fff;
  padding-top: 80px;
}
/*End Gallery*/

@media only screen and (max-width: 994px) {
  .contain .box {
    height: 60%;
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 746px) {
  .contain .box {
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/css/foundation.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/src/jquery.smooth-scroll.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('ul.mainnav a').smoothScroll();

    $('p.subnav a').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      var link = this;
      $.smoothScroll({
        scrollTarget: link.hash
      });
    });

    $('#change-speed').on('click', function() {
      var $p1 = $('ul.mainnav a').first(),
        p1Opts = $p1.smoothScroll('options') || {};

      p1Opts.speed = p1Opts.speed === 1400 ? 400 : 1400;
      $p1.smoothScroll('options', p1Opts);
    });

    $('button.scrollsomething').click(function() {
      $.smoothScroll({
        scrollElement: $('div.scrollme'),
        scrollTarget: '#findme'
      });
      return false;
    });
    $('button.scrollhorz').click(function() {
      $.smoothScroll({
        direction: 'left',
        scrollElement: $('div.scrollme'),
        scrollTarget: '.horiz'
      });
      return false;
    });

  });
</script>

<body>
  <header id="mainHeader">
    <h1 class="hide">Header</h1>
    <div id="wrapper">
      <div id="info">
        <div id="info-content">
          <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/logo2.png" alt="logo" class="logo" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 0.6s and then ease-in over 1.7s">
        </div>
      </div>

      <input type="checkbox" id="menu" name="menu" class="menu-checkbox">
      <div class="menu">
        <label class="menu-toggle" for="menu"><span>Toggle</span>
        </label>
        <div class="container">
          <ul class="mainnav">
            <li><a class="close-btn" href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio#about">ABOUT</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="close-btn" href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio#process">PROCESS</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="close-btn" href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio#work">WORK</a>
            </li>
            <li><a class="close-btn" href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio#contact">CONTACT</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- #wrapper -->
  </header>

  <section id="about">
    <h2 class="hide">About Me</h2> 
    <div id="hey">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <div class="show-for-medium-up">
            <p class="aboutMe" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
              <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/porfolio/images/decor.png" alt="decor" class="decor" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">Hey. I'm Avery
              <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/decor2.png" alt="decor" class="decor" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="show-for-small-only">
          <p class="aboutMe" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
            <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/decor2.png" alt="decor" class="decor1" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">Hey. I'm Avery
            <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/portfolio/images/decor2.png" alt="decor" class="decor2" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="hey">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="small-12 columns">
          <p class="aboutInfo text-center" data-sr="wait 0.2s enter bottom move 10px">I'm an interactive designer from Toronto, Ontario. I fell in love with art at a young age, and at 19 I decided to pursue my passion for design by going into a dual program in Media, Theory, and Production with a specialization in Interactive
            Media Design.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12-columns">
        <img src="images/aves.png" alt="aves" id="aves" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 15px">
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="iLove">
    <h2 class="hide">About continued</h2>
    <div id="outerDiv">
      <div class="small-12-columns">
        <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/a_background2.png" alt="A" class="Aback">
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="show-for-medium-up">
          <h2 class="iLovetitle" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">I love creating beautiful, responsive websites for small businesses.</h2>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="show-for-medium-up">
          <img src="images/line.png" alt="line" class="line">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="process">
    <h2 class="hide">Process</h2> 
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <h2 class="procTitle" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">I have a very simple process for you.</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 columns">
      <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/line.png" alt="line" class="line2">
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
      <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/icon1.png" alt="Icon1" class="icon1" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 0.1s and then ease-in over 1.2s">
      <h3 class="iconTitle text-center">RESEARCH & CONSULT</h3>
      <p class="iconP text-center">I like to take the time to get to know absolutely everything about your business before I even start thinking about the design. I research, consult, and plan, to make sure that I know the purpose of your website, the goal, the target audience, and
        the content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
      <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/icon2.png" alt="Icon1" class="icon1" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 0.4s and then ease-in over 1.2s">
      <h3 class="iconTitle text-center">DESIGN</h3>
      <p class="iconP text-center">Once I have gathered all my information, we can start the fun part! Now we determine the look and feel of your website. I specialize in web design, however if your company also needs a new brand, I would be happy to create an identity for your company.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
      <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/icon3.png" alt="Icon1" class="icon1" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 0.7s and then ease-in over 1.2s">
      <h3 class="iconTitle text-center">DEVELOP</h3>
      <p class="iconP text-center">I like to take the time to get to know absolutely everything about your business before I even start thinking about the design. I research, consult, and plan, to make sure that I know the purpose of your website, the goal, the target audience, and
        the content.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="small-12 medium-6 large-3 columns">
      <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/icon4.png" alt="Icon1" class="icon1" data-sr="opacity 0 wait 1s and then ease-in over 1.2s">
      <h3 class="iconTitle text-center">LAUNCH</h3>
      <p class="iconP text-center">I like to take the time to get to know absolutely everything about your business before I even start thinking about the design. I research, consult, and plan, to make sure that I know the purpose of your website, the goal, the target audience, and
        the content.</p>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="work">
    <h2 class="hide">Work</h2> 
    <div id="lineDivide"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="show-for-medium-up">
          <p class="myWork" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
            <img src="images/decor.png" alt="decor" class="decor" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">My Work
            <img src="images/decor2.png" alt="decor" class="decor" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="small-12 columns">
        <div class="show-for-small-only">
          <p class="myWork" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
            <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/decor_mobile2.png" alt="decor" class="decor1" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">My Work
            <img src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/images/decor_mobile.png" alt="decor" class="decor2" data-sr="wait 0.1s enter bottom move 10px">
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="contain">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class=" box">
        <div class="box-info">
          <a href="http://averyeliasdesign.com/car.html">
            <p class="imgP">Such Bench</p>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section id="contact">
    <h2 class="hide">Contactk</h2> 

  </section>
  <script src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
  <script src="http://averyeliasdesign.com/js/foundation.min.js"></script>
  <script src='http://averyeliasdesign.com/js/scrollReveal.min.js'></script>
  <script>
    var config = {
      mobile: false
    }
    window.sr = new scrollReveal(config);
  </script>
  <script>
    $(document).foundation();
  </script>
```